# List.empty vs. List() vs. new List()

Tags: list, scala, collections, immutability

What the difference between `List.empty`, `List()` and `new List()`? When should I use which?

Comment: You can add `Nil` to that list.

Comment: The correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14815359/843660

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First of all, `new List()` won't work, since the `List` class is abstract. The other two options are defined as follows in [the `List` object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html):

```
override def empty[A]: List[A] = Nil
override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

I.e., they're essentially equivalent, so it's mostly a matter of style. I prefer to use `empty` because I find it clearer, and it cuts down on parentheses.

Answer (score 12):

From the source code of [List](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1) we have:

```
object List extends SeqFactory[List] {
  ...
  override def empty[A]: List[A] = Nil
  override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
  ... 
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {...}
```

So we can see that it is  exactly the same

For completeness, you can also use `Nil`.

Answer (score 4):

For the creations of an empty list, as others have said, you can use the one that looks best to you.

However for pattern matching against an empty List, you can only use Nil

```
scala> List()
res1: List[Nothing] = List()

scala> res1 match {
     | case Nil => "empty"
     | case head::_ => "head is " + head
     | }
res2: java.lang.String = empty
```

*EDIT* : Correction: `case List()` works too, but `case List.empty` does not compile