# How to map method name X to method name Y in Scala like in List

Tags: list, scala

Referring to the answer of the following question:

[List.empty vs. List() vs. new List()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686213/list-empty-vs-list-vs-new-list)

How did the developers of Scala map the method `apply[A](xs: A*)` defined in the `List` **object**, to be usable as `List[A](cs: A*)`?

Also how did they translate `aListInstance(n: Int)` to the method `apply(n: Int)` (which returns the n'th element of the list) defined in the `List` **class**?

In both cases I'm calling the `apply()` methods without writing `.apply()` in my code. How does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because the Scala Language Specification says so.

```
foo(bar)
```

is translated to

```
foo.apply(bar)
```

just like

```
foo.bar = baz
```

is translated to

```
foo.bar_=(baz)
```

and

```
foo(bar) = baz
```

is translated to

```
foo.update(bar, baz)
```

and

```
foo bar baz
```

is translated to

```
foo.bar(baz)
```

and

```
foo bar_: baz
```

is translated to

```
baz.bar_:(foo)
```

and so on and so forth.